# Persistent in-place access to Rust collection element's value object

Tags: rust

let's say I need to sort and collect certain tokens incoming from a list into buckets, where the bucket ids can be repeated. Sample input:

```
Bucket_A:
x
y
Bucket_B:
v
w
Bucket_A:
z
```

In my old C++ times, I would do some regex or similar string matching and use a  `map<string,vector<string>>` for storage, and then iterate over lines, and there would be hint variable of iterator type (for that map) which points at the recently detected target (within the map). I.e. when a "Bucket..." line comes, the hint variable changes to whatever  `map::emplace(name)` produces as iterator. And then we use that iterator to insert values to the bucket in later line processing loop cycles. That works perfectly well as long as the container implementation guarantees sufficient iterator stability (i.e. fixed memory location, works with tree-based dictionaries, for example).

Now, in Rust, this method is not so easy to represent. The closest thing I have found so far is `HashMap::entry()` or `BTreeMap::entry()`. They return an "Entry" enum but that is still subject to Rust's oversensitive borrowing rules, and I cannot easily push it out of the if-block scope where the particular line was processed.

Is there any sane way to work around those restrictions? I really don't want to do "lame" things like saving the entry key as string and re-access that entry every time by key (that would be pointless CPU cycles waste).

Comment: Why not simply remembering which bucket the element you are reading should go into, and create the vector outside of the map. When you read a bucket (or reach the end of the input), you first insert that vector into the map with the bucket name as key, then update the the bucket name and create a new, empty vector?

Comment: @jthulhu the only issue with that is "bucket ids can be repeated", which means you'll be creating an extra `Vec` for each repeat. But otherwise it's a good solution.

Comment: @drewtato indeed. This can be patched by taking the vector from the map if it previously was there, or create a new one, instead of always creating a new one.

Comment: The purpose of the dictionary is to be the single source of truth, i.e. you come back to the same destination easily and keep using it without additional extra cost. Populating yet another Vec and merging in the end gets more error-prone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just barely possible in the same way as the C++ method. The important parts are:

- pre-accessing the first element so that `current_entry` is always initialized.
- only accessing `map` when when replacing `current_entry`.

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1d1a2f92ae03eea3f8dcc8a04b51ca23)

```rs
fn read_to_map(input: &str) -> HashMap<&str, Vec<&str>> {
    let mut map = HashMap::new();
    let mut iter = input.trim().lines().map(str::trim);
    let Some(first) = iter.next() else { return map; };
    let mut current_entry = map.entry(first).or_default();

    for line in iter {
        if line.ends_with(':') {
            current_entry = map.entry(line).or_default();
        } else {
            current_entry.push(line);
        }
    }
    map
}
```

Removing the colon, using a regex, or making a `HashMap<String, Vec<String>>` are easy changes, but more complex changes may make this unusable.